# HP ProBook 4530s unable to shutdown, restart, sleep or hibernate

Tags: windows-8.1

I've a ProBook 4530s laptop that recently had the hard drive replaced with a Samsung Evo 840 SSD and I used its previous HDD as a secondary using the laptop's upgrade bay and a HDD Caddy.

I've also installed a fresh copy of Windows 8.1 Update 1 and downloaded the latest drivers from HP support page and Softpaq but now whenever try to shutdown, restart, sleep or hibernate my laptop the monitor turns black and then everything stops working.

In case of shutdown and restart I noticed that the Wireless indicator (the little white LED on the top right of the keboard) turns to orange and if I wait for about 5 to 10 minutes sometimes a BSOD very fast comes and goes.

Comment: Interestingly, even since this post, I will not get any BSOD. Just a black screen and high fan usage.

Comment: After more investigation, it seems that the problem is with HDD Caddy or Upgrade bay because if I remove the second HDD (Caddy) everything will work as they should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone have this problem, I found the solution in a forum.

For reference there is a white switch next to the SATA connector. Once I pushed it in the arrow direction toward the SATA connector, the problem solved!

Here is the link: [HDD caddy question!](http://www.tonymacx86.com/hp-probook-4530s/78645-hdd-caddy-question.html#post531506)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.